# events hash for dynamically generated buttons in backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a template in underscore having a button inside it. I want a click event to be mentioned in the event hash in the backbone view.

template code is:

```
<script type="text/template" id="ledgerListing">

<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="addLedgerButton">Add Ledger</button>

</script>
```

View Code is:

```
app.ledgerView=Backbone.View.extend({

el:"#container",

template:_.template($("#ledgerListing").html()),

events: {},


   initialize: function(){

    },

    render: function()
{
    this.$el.html(template())

}

});
```

Now how to specify the click event in the event hash for the button with id addLedgerButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can add events as the following, (format should be *`event type`* and *`a space`* and *`the element`*

```
events: {
  'click #addLedgerButton': 'myclick'
},
```

and define a function named `myclick`:

```
myclick: function () {
  alert(1);
}
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/w2jm7/